# Can postman automatically open a new browser window after response?

Tags: postman, postman-testcase

Example:

I'd made a request and got response from the API.

**Response as below**

```
"status": "SUCCESS"
"redirect_url": "https://www.google.com.tw/"
```

I need redirect_url automatically open with a new browser window without click.
Does anyone know how to do it?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Postman is not for front end automation it's for backed ,. You could save that response in a variable and open it in another request . But cannot. Open browser

Comment: What do you want to achieve/ do in the browser? Postman also can automate interaction with websites, to a certain degree

Comment: @PDHide got it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ChristianBaumann redirect_url is just like a form page, then I should file in some data. thanks anyway.

Comment: You can achieve that with cheerio in Postman